# Ektron eSync to load balanced production CMS servers

Tags: ektron

I'm looking at a way of having no downtime when an eSync is run against our production environment.

Currently we have 2x Windows 2012 IIS servers running CMS400 v7.5 sitting behind a varnish web cache instance.

When eSync is run, it causes a site outage of up to a minute or so due to the ektron services being restarted. Is there a way to stagger an e-Sync deployment so that only one node is down at any one time?

I have set up health checks so that clients will only be directed to "healthy" CMS nodes.

TIA

Iain

Answer (score 1):

Typically people will use eSync to synchronize content only (i.e. a database sync). Synchronization of files is best done by deploying files manually (i.e. a template sync) .  Although eSync gives you the option of deploying files, it doesn't mean you have to do it this way.

Best practice is like so:

1. Remove Web Server 1 from the load balancer so that only Web Server 2 is active.
2. Manually deploy your code to Web Server 1
3. Test that Web Server 1 loads correctly, this gives IIS time to reload the site following code changes.
4. Put Web Server 1 back into the load balancer.
5. Remove Web Server 2 from the load balancer so that only Web Server 1 is active.
6. Manually deploy code to Web Server 2
7. Test Web Server 2
8. Add Web Server 2 back into the load balancer

This method means there is no downtime and no slowdown of your public website.  You also reduce the possibility of new code breaking your public website due to unforeseen problems.

Answer (score 0):

We've had this same problem. Our solution is to not use Ektron load balancing, and have separate databases and esync connections to the individual servers.

The downsides are-

- Need to run esync twice
- User-generated content won't be shared between servers until after sync and re-sync.

Otherwise, you can schedule the esync to occur at a low priority time, so that the outage has minimal impact.

Comment: This is not good advice, I wouldn't suggest anybody do this. The OP's problem was not with load balancing but with syncing to production. The OP experiences downtime following a sync, due to restarting of services and possibly deployment of new code. In either case the best advice is to contact Ektron support. Each setup has differences so it is best to run through it with one of Ektron's people.